# ESRI customizing the home button gis javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Overall Question First then please read: How can I remove the SelectedBusStops and SelectedBusRoutes and Zoom to map:map when user clicks home button?

Here is what I am trying to do.  I have a JavaScript Application that utilizes that ArcGIS API for JavaScript along with some Ajax and JQuery in there.  I'm trying to customize the Home Button or create my own, that can do more than simply zoom to the initial extent.  I tried doing this on my own by creating a button that called a function goHome().  Then within that function I did things like remove the highlighted Selected route from the list and then scrolled to the top of the route list and removed any bus arrival times that may have been populate when a user clicked on a bus stop to show times.  I've got it to do everything I want so far except remove the current highlighted (Selected Route) along with the Current Bus Stops that are associated with the selected Route and then Zoom to my initial map extent.

I was trying to do something like setting the setDefinitionExpression of the feature layer I wanted to modify, but due to where this function is in my code it cannot see them.  When I put this function inside of the main function it gives me the ReferenceError: goHome is not defined.  So I put it outside of the main function and everything works so far but can't figure out how to get the featureLayers to go away. It will give me an error saying:
ReferenceError: selectedBusStops is not defined
selectedBusStops.setDefinitionExpression("Route is null");

When a user clicks on a route in the list it will then go in and set a definitionExpression to show only that Selected Route.  Like this:

```js
selectedBusStops.setDefinitionExpression("Route like '%" + routeSlice + "%'");
```

Here are my FeatureLayers:  ** Here was my issues with not being able to use these in another function.  I declared these with the 'var' and that made them local to the function they were in.  Removed the 'var' and problem solved, I can now at least clear the features. **

```js
var selectedBusRoute = new FeatureLayer("http://PROD_RTC_SystemMap/MapServer/4", {
  mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SELECTION,
  outFields: ["*"],
  infoTemplate: selectedBusRouteTemplate
});
var selectedBusStops = new FeatureLayer("http://PROD_RTC_SystemMap/MapServer/0", {
  mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
  outFields: ["*"],
  infoTemplate: selectedBusStopsTemplate
});
```

I was thinking if there was a way to manipulate the esri/dijit/HomeButton somehow to do all of this or am I on the right track?  [Esri/github/homebutton](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-dijit-home-button-js)

Thanks for taking the time to read this and I appreciate all input (even those that say my code looks like a*#).

Here is the code I have for the function that is getting called:

```js
function goHome() {
  // Reset the Accordian Content Panes and fix naming
  var newTitle = "Bus Arrival Times";
  dijit.byId("pane3").set("title", newTitle);
  var container = dijit.byId("container");
  container.selectChild("RTCBusroutes", true);

  // This will remove old values in Bus Arrival Time pane so Bus Arrival Times will clear
  var results = document.getElementById("results");
  var rowCount = results.rows.length;
  for (var x = rowCount - 1; x > 0; x--) {
    results.deleteRow(x);
  }

  // Removes the Highlight from the currently selected Item in the RTC Bus Routes List pane
  $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

  // Scrolls to the top of the List in the RTC Bus Routes Content Pane List
  $('#RTCBusroutes').scrollTop(0);

  // Remove Currently Selected Bus Routes

  // Remove Currently Selectes Bus Stops

  // Zoom to Map Extent

}
```

Here is the Button I added:

```html
<button id="homeImg" onclick="goHome()">
  <img id="myImg" src="img/home.png" />
</button>
```

CSS for the Home Button #homeImg

```css
/* for the Home Button CSS */

#homeImg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 138px;
  left: 28px;
  z-index: 8;
  background-color: #888888;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with your code?

Comment: I'll work on it... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear a featureLayer by calling the .clear() method on it, then smwill clear all graphics in the layer.

If you only want to clear the selections call the .clearSelections() method.

There is more documenta ion here on other featurelayer methods:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#methods

Comment: Ok, Ok, I was declaring the featureLayers in a function and used the var to declare them.  Unfortunately, this made them local to that function.  Removed the var to make the global and problem solved.  Frustrating when you miss something like that.  Now I just need to get the zoom to initial extent and I'm golden.

Comment: Glad its sorted.  I still recommend declaring them (using var) but just do it at the document level.  outside of the functions.  Just good practice.